# Is there a way to model schrödinger's wave equations in blender?

Tags: geometry, mathematics

I have the task to model the orbitals of an atom in blender for an animation. I know the orbitals of electron around an atom can be gotten from Schrödinger's wave equations. How would I be able to model that in blender?

I can try to explain a bit more about what is going on. (I am as lost as you are) The Schrödinger wave equation is a linear partial differential equation. The Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom (or a hydrogen-like atom) is

${\displaystyle E\psi =-{\frac {\hbar ^{2}}{2\mu }}\nabla ^{2}\psi -{\frac {q^{2}}{4\pi \varepsilon _{0}r}}\psi }$

The Schrödinger for a hydrogen atom can be solved by separation of variables. Spherical polar coordinates are most convenient according to Wikipedia.
${\displaystyle \psi (r,\theta ,\varphi )=R(r)Y_{\ell }^{m}(\theta ,\varphi )=R(r)\Theta (\theta )\Phi (\varphi )}$

please read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Three-dimensional_examples under hydrogen atom. Also to add when modeled in blender they should look a lot like https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/app/uploads/sites/25/2016/05/CNX_Chem_06_03_Oshapes.jpg

Comment: Can it be parametric?

Comment: could you show some background information/ examples for those that dont now about physics? Maby its an easy behavior and the math just stands in the way ;)

Comment: Something like in this movie here? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lH9SNnQCs54 How precise do you need your model to be? If it's just a visual aid for the lecture you could just make the model manually, no need for fancy coding/maths.

Comment: I presume this can be achieved using a volumetric material with the equation defining the density at any particular XYZ in the volume. However, the physics is a bit beyond me. Can you formulate the equation into a form that doesn't assume knowledge of the physics involved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to find a tool that did everything for you. The tool is here: https://github.com/Niuskir/Electron-Orbitals-Blender-3D

Comment: Hello. The initial question is very interesting. So, could you provide more details in your answer so that it does not rely only on an external link? Thanks by advance.

Comment: Please expand...If the link disappears then the answer will be like Schrödinger's cat...